# Enable a third button after two files have been uploaded

Tags: php, ajax, forms, button

I have 3 buttons and I have the code to upload the files.

#### First button

I want to be able to click and upload a file. After this action I would also like to disable the button.

#### Second button

Same as the first.

#### Third button

After both files are uploaded I want to enable the third button and show a form using an iframe.

How do I code this? Or can you point me toward some tutorials?

Comment: This programming question will be move to the correct place. Follow it. You may also need to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could understand your question, you can disable the buttons this way after they are clicked:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.disabled = true;">
```

And show the form in iframe using scr attribute of the iframe.

```
<iframe src="path-to-file-of-your-form.php">
```